# Laravel 4: accessing values from redirect '->withInput()'

Tags: php, laravel-4

I've got a long, complex form with several 'conditional' fields - field B only shows if field A is marked as 'Yes' for example.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="{{ $errors->has('happy') ? ' has-error' : false }}">
    {{Form::label('happy', 'Are you happy?')}}
    {{Form::select('happy', array('' => '--', 'Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),(!empty($input['happy']) ? $input['happy'] : null), ['class'=>'dependent']);}}
</div>
<div class="{{ !empty($input['happy']) && $input['happy'] == 'Yes' ? null : 'hidden'}} dependent" data-dependent-field="happy" data-dependent-value="Yes">
    {{Form::label('second-field', 'Only asked if you\'re happy')}}
    {{Form::textarea('second-field',!empty($input['second-field']) ? $input['second-field'] : null)}}
</div>
```

The problem is when the form is submitted if there's a validation error in the second-field, the original input isn't being recognized and the `hidden`class is still being added to the second set of fields.

```
 {{ !empty($input['happy']) && $input['happy'] == 'Yes' ? null : 'hidden'}}
```

That code works when reloading the form with data to edit, but not when the validation error is being sent through. The validation code looks like this:

```
        if($validation->fails()){
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors())->with(['flash_message'=>'Please check your inputs again.']);
        }
```

I'm guessing I'm not referencing the return data correctly, but can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm already using jQuery to expand the fields when the input is changed, but this doesn't take care of the fields when it reloads after a validation error.

**EDIT FOR MORE CLAIRTY:**

Here's an example. If I select Yes, but then leave the 'why' answer blank and it's a required field, when Laravel does the `back()->withErrors()` bit, the text area doesn't show on screen.

```
<div class="row {{ $errors->has('happy') ? ' has-error' : false }}">
    {{Form::label('happy', 'Field Label', ['class'=>'span12'])}}
    <div class="span3">
        {{Form::select('happy', array('' => '--', 'Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),(!empty($input['happy']) ? $input['happy'] : null), ['class'=>'dependent']);}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="{{ !empty($input['happy']) && $input['happy'] == 'No' ? null : 'hidden'}} dependent" data-dependent-field="happy" data-dependent-value="No">

            <div {{ $errors->has('why-not-happy') ? ' has-error' : false }}">
                {{Form::label('why-not-happy', 'Why aren\'nt you happy?')}}
                {{Form::textarea('why-not-happy',!empty($input['why-not-happy']) ? $input['why-not-happy'] : null)}}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the function in the controller which accepts the form values?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the problem is that it could be addressed through jQuery because this is something you need to achieve before submitting the form. The $input['happy'] only gets a value only after you submit.

Getting back to finding a solution to your problem.

You may include this as snippet at the end of the view or a separate .js file.

The jQuery code could be as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
  $(function() {
    //you may assign an id to the dropdown, just in case, and mention it as a selector  
    $('select.dependent').change(function(d){
        d.preventDefault();
        var selectValue = this.val();
        if(selectValue !='happy' || selectValue.length === 0){
           //Whatever you want to achieve when the selected value is NOT happy or empty
           $('div.dependent').addClass('hidden');
        }    
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if it didn't.

Comment: Thanks, but that bit I already have. When Laravel returns the form w/ errors,   the fields in the hidden section aren't showing because it's not picking up the input. Let me update with a better example...